# WSS 3.0 - Running Timer Jobs Manually

Tags: wss-3.0, timer-jobs

I am trying to troubleshoot why my timer job is not working in WSS 3.0. Is there anyway to run a timer job manually in WSS 3.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there is an out of the box method available.  You can do it by manipulating the start and stop times and activating / de-activating it. But it is of course a little clunky.

There is a tool on codeplex available that "kind of" lets you do this from Central Administration:

http://zstimerjob.codeplex.com/

The "kind of" is in that for one-off schedules of jobs, it creates copies of the timer job.